# Pandas dataframe : Replace value according case conditions

Tags: python, pandas

There is dataframe with one column

```
disposition
---------
NO ANSWER
ANSWERED
FAILED
BUSY
ERROR
WARNING
CANCEL
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'disposition': ['NO ANSWER', 'ANSWERED', 'FAILED', 'BUSY', 'ERROR', 'WARNING', 'CANCEL']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

How to replace values according conditions:

```
  WHEN disposition = 'NO ANSWER' THEN 0
  WHEN disposition = 'ANSWERED'  THEN 1
  WHEN disposition = 'FAILED'    THEN 2
  WHEN disposition = 'BUSY'      THEN 3
  ELSE 9
```

Wished result is

```
disposition
---------
    0
    1
    2
    3
    9
    9
    9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Code**

```
m = {'NO ANSWER': 0, 'ANSWERED': 1, 'FAILED': 2, 'BUSY': 3}
df['disposition'] = df['disposition'].map(m).fillna(9).astype('int')
```

df

```
disposition
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   9
5   9
6   9
```

Answer (score 1):

The `map` option is a clean way. Another option would be to do a merge, or a replace. You could also use `case_when`, which at the moment works only on series. You have to pass a list of tuples, where the first entry in the tuple is the condition, while the second entry in the tuple is the replacement.

```py
caselist = [(df.disposition.eq('NO ANSWER'), 0), 
            (df.disposition.eq('ANSWERED'), 1), 
            (df.disposition.eq('FAILED'), 2), 
            (df.disposition.eq('BUSY'),3)]

df.assign(outcome=pd.Series(9,index=df.index).case_when(caselist))
  disposition  outcome
0   NO ANSWER        0
1    ANSWERED        1
2      FAILED        2
3        BUSY        3
4       ERROR        9
5     WARNING        9
6      CANCEL        9
```